# Pulling AD user data not working on telephone/employeeID PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, active-directory

This script isn't pulling ad user data like expected.This code is pulling the Name and UserPrincipalName correctly, but then it is blank for the rest of the fields.I know the fields that I am pulling are not blank. The result should be a csv file with the select-objects showing.Am I missing something? I am not getting an error message as well.

```
$OUpath = 'ou=*****,OU=****,DC=****,DC=****,DC=****,DC=****'
$ExportPath = 'c:\scripts\users_in_ou2.csv'
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath | 
Select-object Name,UserPrincipalName,mobile,mail,telephoneNumber,employeeID | 
Export-Csv -NoType $ExportPath
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell get-aduser which properties you want. There probably a better way too do it but this should get you the result you want

```
$OUpath = 'ou=*****,OU=****,DC=****,DC=****,DC=****,DC=****'
$ExportPath = 'c:\scripts\users_in_ou2.csv'
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath -Properties Name,UserPrincipalName,Mobile,EmailAddress,telephoneNumber,employeeID | 
Select-object Name,UserPrincipalName,Mobile,EmailAddress,telephoneNumber,employeeID | 
Export-Csv -NoType $ExportPath
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. Thank you. I'm curious though why it allowed Name and UserPrincipalName to show up in my original code but not the other fields.

Comment: By default, a `Get-ADUser` will show you `DistinguishedName`, `Enabled`, `GivenName`, `Name`, `ObjectClass`, `ObjectGUID`, `SamAccountName`, `SID`, `Surname` and `UserPrincipleName`. All other properties will need to be requested explicitly via the `-properties` param